# Default Stack Exchange behavior interferes with my "Mark answers as favorites" code?

Tags: support, discussion, answers, scripts, favorite

I'm developing a browser extension that lets users mark answers as favorites. The default Stack Exchange behavior when the favorite button is clicked messes everything up, though. Even if I set my own event listener to replace the default behavior, it seems to automatically undo my code and do the default behavior.

[image]

How can I "turn off" default Stack Exchange behaviors?

Comment: This needs an MCVE.   Depending on the circumstances it may also belong on SO or MetaSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First can I say, you might want to use your own icon. [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) is a very useful and easy to use icon toolkit that lets you add icons with simple CSS classes. You could use http://fontawesome.io/icon/star/ if you want :)

---

However, if you want to use SE's button, in Javascript, if you want to override an event handler, you need to `return false;` or call [`event.stopPropogation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) (jQuery) at the begininng of the event handler function.

So, if you are using jQuery, to disable SE's handler:

```
$('.star-off, .star-on').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropogation();
    //your custom handler code here
});
```

This makes sure the event doesn't reach the DOM so it doesn't do the original action. You'll find lots of questions on Stack Overflow relating to this if you want to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use the default button**.  That's bad UI anyway.
Add your own favorite button for each answer.

And, since you will be using your own classes, like:

```html
<a class="myStarOff" href="#" data-ansID="1234" title="Click to add as favorite answer (click again to undo)">
favorite</a>

<a class="myStarOn" href="#" data-ansID="56789" title="Click to remove from favorite answers (click again to redo)">
favorite</a>
```

...and your own event handlers; there will be no conflict.